# MEMS-FPI tunable filter

Tags: amplifier, pwm, dc-dc-converter, precision

I've got to control a tunable filter on a MEMS-FPI C14273 IR sensor. It works by inputing a voltage on a range from 25 to 48 V, wich makes the lens move. It needs to be precise because if i go over 48V by only 0.5V it can break. My professor talked about a switching capacitor converter but I can't find enough information on this. So basically I'm searching for something that can take a PWM or analog signal 0-5V and convert it to 25-48V.

https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/c14273_kacc1265e.pdf
https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/mems-fpi_kacc9008e.pdf

Comment: What current is the load?

Comment: there is no current limits rated on the datasheet, only a Voltage limit.

Comment: In a previous job I worked with very expensive FPI filters. We drove them off of function generators programmed with the device absolute maximum voltage to avoid damaging them. Since your professor is probably not looking for mass production, I would consider this.

Comment: @SimonJanelle-Bombardier There is probably a capacitance from which you can compute your current needs. Do this before you buy anything! By the way, that isn't much of a datasheet, contact hamamatsu and ask for a more detailed one. They usually have then on request.

Comment: Added the link to the more detailed one, I still can't find a capacitance value anywhere for the tunable filter